# Save disk space on the server side. Decompress gz in the browser (JS)

Tags: javascript, browser, compression, gzip, server-side

I'm looking for the way to save disk space.

I have a great amount of json txt files. And I want to gzip it on the server side.

How should I properly ungzip it with javascript?

snippet:

```
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'file.txt.gz', false); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      // ungzip( xhr.responseText ); ????
      }
   }
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Buy more disk space, and use gzip transfer encoding.

Comment: I can't see 1TB disk space filled by txt files without compression.

Comment: Alright in that case, write a server-side script to send them pre-gzipped transfer encoding and don't support clients that can't use this transfer encoding.  Most support it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [javascript inflator](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate).  I can't vouch for it.  I simply point to it.